# i have a csv file i need to calculate my vpn clients session duration from time column please any one can support

Tags: powershell

[my csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mN70X.png)

```
#This is my code
$input_path = "F:\myfile.txt" $output_file = ‘F:\myfile.csv’ $regex = '\b(time|remip|user|msg)=("[^"]*"|\S+)' Select-String $input_path -AllMatches -Pattern $regex | ForEach-Object { # Use an aux. ordered hashtable to capture the matches # as key-value pairs. $oht = [ordered] @{} foreach ($m in $_.Matches) { $oht[$m.Groups[1].Value] = $m.Groups[2].Value.Trim('"') } [pscustomobject] $oht } | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation $output_file -Append
```

Comment: can you please share any example i dont have as much idea of coding ..

Answer (score 0):

*Q&D = quick and dirty*

You can just Read and Convert to CSV, then cherry-pick what you want. Of course, this is just one way, and you'd need to decide if it is acceptable to you. Otherwise, wait for another to supply some more elegant/better or do that on your own from what I show below.

However, not all your records are the same. So, you'd need to tweak as needed for your detail. For example only that LogStamp data.

Here's what I mean.

```
# Create log file
'
2022-07-26 20:41:19 Local7.Info 10.10.50.14 date=2022-07-26 time=20:41:19 devname="FortiGate-201F" devid="FG201FT920901378" logid="0101039424" type="event" subtype="vpn" level="information" vd="root" eventtime=1658850140906853257 tz="+0500" logdesc="SSL VPN tunnel up" action="tunnel-up" tunneltype="ssl-web" tunnelid=850652354 remip=1.1.1.1 user="abc" group="N/A" dst_host="N/A" reason="login successfully" msg="SSL tunnel established"

2022-07-26 20:42:19 Local7.Info 10.10.50.14 date=2022-07-26 time=20:42:19 devname="FortiGate-201F" devid="FG201FT920901378" logid="0101039424" type="event" subtype="vpn" level="information" vd="root" eventtime=1658850140906853257 tz="+0500" logdesc="SSL VPN tunnel up" action="tunnel-up" tunneltype="ssl-web" tunnelid=850652354 remip=2.2.2.2 user="xyz" group="N/A" dst_host="N/A" reason="login successfully" msg="SSL tunnel established"

2022-07-26 20:43:04 Local7.Notice 10.10.50.14 date=2022-07-26 time=20:43:04 devname="FortiGate-201F" devid="FG201FT920901378" logid="0102043040" type="event" subtype="user" level="notice" vd="root" eventtime=1658850185820400745 tz="+0500" logdesc="Authentication logout" srcip="1.1.1.1" user="abc" authserver="N/A" action="auth-logout" status="logout" msg="User abc removed from auth logon"

2022-07-26 20:43:08 Local7.Notice 10.10.50.14 date=2022-07-26 time=20:43:08 devname="FortiGate-201F" devid="FG201FT920901378" logid="0102043040" type="event" subtype="user" level="notice" vd="root" eventtime=1658850185820400745 tz="+0500" logdesc="Authentication logout" srcip="2.2.2.2" user="xyz" authserver="N/A" action="auth-logout" status="logout" msg="User xyz removed from auth logon"
' | Out-File -FilePath 'D:\Temp\LogFile.txt' -Force

'All records detail'
(
$LogData = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\LogFile.txt' | 
ForEach-Object {
    $PSItem -replace '<?(\w+)=', ','
} | 
ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ',' -Header LogStamp, date, time, devname, devid, 
                                       logid, type, subtype, level, vd, 
                                       eventtime, tz, logdesc, action, 
                                       tunneltype, tunnelid, remip, user, 
                                       group, dst_host, reason, msg 
)



# Results
<#
All records detail


LogStamp   : 2022-07-26 20:41:19 Local7.Info 10.10.50.14 
date       : 2022-07-26 
time       : 20:41:19 
devname    : FortiGate-201F
devid      : FG201FT920901378
logid      : 0101039424
type       : event
subtype    : vpn
level      : information
vd         : root
eventtime  : 1658850140906853257 
tz         : +0500
logdesc    : SSL VPN tunnel up
action     : tunnel-up
tunneltype : ssl-web
tunnelid   : 850652354 
remip      : 1.1.1.1 
user       : abc
group      : N/A
dst_host   : N/A
reason     : login successfully
msg        : SSL tunnel established

LogStamp   : 2022-07-26 20:42:19 Local7.Info 10.10.50.14 
date       : 2022-07-26 
time       : 20:42:19 
devname    : FortiGate-201F
devid      : FG201FT920901378
logid      : 0101039424
type       : event
subtype    : vpn
level      : information
vd         : root
eventtime  : 1658850140906853257 
tz         : +0500
logdesc    : SSL VPN tunnel up
action     : tunnel-up
tunneltype : ssl-web
tunnelid   : 850652354 
remip      : 2.2.2.2 
user       : xyz
group      : N/A
dst_host   : N/A
reason     : login successfully
msg        : SSL tunnel established

LogStamp   : 2022-07-26 20:43:04 Local7.Notice 10.10.50.14 
date       : 2022-07-26 
time       : 20:43:04 
devname    : FortiGate-201F
devid      : FG201FT920901378
logid      : 0102043040
type       : event
subtype    : user
level      : notice
vd         : root
eventtime  : 1658850185820400745 
tz         : +0500
logdesc    : Authentication logout
action     : 1.1.1.1
tunneltype : abc
tunnelid   : N/A
remip      : auth-logout
user       : logout
group      : User abc removed from auth logon
dst_host   : 
reason     : 
msg        : 

LogStamp   : 2022-07-26 20:43:08 Local7.Notice 10.10.50.14 
date       : 2022-07-26 
time       : 20:43:08 
devname    : FortiGate-201F
devid      : FG201FT920901378
logid      : 0102043040
type       : event
subtype    : user
level      : notice
vd         : root
eventtime  : 1658850185820400745 
tz         : +0500
logdesc    : Authentication logout
action     : 2.2.2.2
tunneltype : xyz
tunnelid   : N/A
remip      : auth-logout
user       : logout
group      : User xyz removed from auth logon
dst_host   : 
reason     : 
msg        :
#> 

'LogStamp data'
$LogData.LogStamp
# Results
<#
LogStamp data
2022-07-26 20:41:19 Local7.Info 10.10.50.14 
2022-07-26 20:42:19 Local7.Info 10.10.50.14 
2022-07-26 20:43:04 Local7.Notice 10.10.50.14 
2022-07-26 20:43:08 Local7.Notice 10.10.50.14
#>
```

As you can see. all I did here, was parse one record to get all the detail to create the property headers, then dumped them (via RegEx) to add custom headers for the CSV properties, and lastly just referenced the one of interest.

As for your TimeSpan calculations, there are lots of samples on SO, in the PS help files, and all over the web you could review and work through, as that is a pretty common daily thing.

For example, from your data, my example above, simply choose a format and process it via the PS cmdlet, or .Net namespace:

```
$LogTime = $LogData.LogStamp -replace 'Local.*|\r\n\r\n'
# Results
<#
2022-07-26 20:41:19 
2022-07-26 20:42:19 
2022-07-26 20:43:04 
2022-07-26 20:43:08
#>


$LogData.LogStamp -replace 'Local.*|\s|\D|\r\n\r\n'
# Results
<#
20220726204119
20220726204219
20220726204304
20220726204308
#>

New-TimeSpan -Start $LogTime[0] -End $LogTime[3]
# Results
<#
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 1
Seconds           : 49
Milliseconds      : 0
Ticks             : 1090000000
TotalDays         : 0.00126157407407407
TotalHours        : 0.0302777777777778
TotalMinutes      : 1.81666666666667
TotalSeconds      : 109
TotalMilliseconds : 109000
#>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions it helps me and i found some code from different sources kindly view my code and my results now i want to calculate only connection session time from this csv file time filed

Comment: time   remip        user    msg  
01:12:47 11.18.2.34 abc SSL tunnel established  
01:12:49  abc User abc added to auth logon  
01:13:27 11.16.2.34 xyz SSL tunnel established  
01:13:28  xyz User xyz added to auth logon  
01:14:08 11.16.2.34 xyz SSL tunnel shutdown  
01:14:08  xyz User xyz removed from auth logon  
01:15:22 11.19.2.34 efg SSL tunnel established  
01:15:23 11.19.2.34 efg SSL tunnel established  
01:17:11 11.19.2.34 efg SSL tunnel shutdown  
01:17:12  efg User efg removed from auth logon  
01:17:10 11.18.2.34 abc SSL tunnel shutdown  
01:17:12  abc User abc removed f

Comment: here is my code `    $input_path = "F:\myfile.txt" 
    $output_file = ‘F:\myfile.csv’

$regex = '\b(time|remip|user|msg)=("[^"]*"|\S+)'

Select-String $input_path -AllMatches -Pattern $regex | ForEach-Object {

    # Use an aux. ordered hashtable to capture the matches
    # as key-value pairs.
    $oht = [ordered] @{}
    foreach ($m in $_.Matches) {
      $oht[$m.Groups[1].Value] = $m.Groups[2].Value.Trim('"')
    }

    [pscustomobject] $oht

} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation $output_file -Append
`

Comment: No worries. For this to be better followed. Do not put text samples, and code blocks in the comments. Update your original post. Properly format them using the SO-provided tools. You can certainly use RegEx on the whole file vs Select-String, and I choose the *-Csv approach to allow you to use built properties.

Comment: please help i will be very thankful to you in this

Comment: ok i did as you suggested